# Why buoyant force equals weight of fluid displaced?

Tags: forces, fluid-statics, density, buoyancy

I know how formula of buoyant force come (upthrust=$V\rho g$).I also know its derivation.
I can understand why buoyant force equals weight of fluid displaced according to this equation but that understanding is mathematically.
I want a intuitive understanding why buoyant force equals weight of fluid displaced.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Buoyant Force $V\rho g$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/135574/)

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/494969/why-is-there-an-upthrust/494998#494998

Comment: The surrounding fluid doesn't know there is an object there instead of fluid.  So it exerts the same force on the object as if there was fluid there.  That force would be the weight of the fluid that filled the space below the surface that the object now occupies.